# FIX message parsing of Custom Message using Quickfixj library

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

What are the files in which we would need to add the new custom messages apart from the required datadictionary (FIX50SP2.xml and FIX50SP2.modified.xml) so as to generate the custom message classes and facilitate successful parsing of the same ? Even after having added the new message definition in the xmls and after successful generation of the classes, the parsing of the message gets failed in the acceptor class in the onMessage method while extracting the repeating groups. Seems like the groups in the custom messages are not getting initialized at the acceptor end after receiving. The size is always 0 in the case where as for the other predefined messages, the groups and the fields are initialized and hence retrievable. Would be great if someone can provide insight into it!

Refer: How to retrieve repeating groups from the FIX messages using quickfixj library?

Comment: Please provide your session config.

Comment: [default]
ApplicationID=server
ConnectionType=acceptor
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:50:00
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=6
SocketUseSSL=N
SocketTcpNoDelay=N
SocketAcceptAddress=127.0.0.1
SocketAcceptPort=3000
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=resources/FIX50SP2.xml

[session]
BeginString=FIXT1.1
SocketAcceptPort=9877
SenderCompID=target-id
Timezone=America/New_York
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
ValidateFieldsHaveValues=N
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
LogonTimeout=5
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=N

Comment: Maybe the wrong dictionary is picked up? Could you try specifying an absolute path? Could you also try to explicitly specify a session and app dictionary?

Comment: The issue was with the datadictionary . It is resolved now ! Thanks for the suggestion.